# JavaScript Image Preload in function

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

first of all I don't really know anything about JavaScript.
I have a website slideshow with the following code:

```css
//* Slideshow 1 *//
var slider_img_1 = document.querySelector(".image_slide_1");
var images_1 = ["fabric1_1.jpg", "fabric1_2.jpg", "fabric1_3.jpg", "fabric1_4.jpg", "fabric1_5.jpg"];
var i = 0;
//* Slideshow 2 *//
var slider_img_2 = document.querySelector(".image_slide_2");
var images_2 = ["book1_1.jpg", "book1_2.jpg", "book1_3.jpg", "book1_4.jpg", "book1_5.jpg", "book1_6.jpg", "book1_7.jpg"];
var j = 0;
```

When clicking on the slideshow the images cycle through.
Is it possible to let the images inside the var brackets preload, because currently they only start loading when clicking on the slideshow, which takes a lot of time in my case.

I hope you understand my question well. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

In this use case (if you need to load images with JavaScript) it would probably be best to append you images in to HTML when page is loaded and hide them, with CSS for example, when they shouldn't be visible.